# Is it possible to add some text in genesis block?

Tags: polkadot

We are wondering if there is a way to put text/data into the genesis block. We would like to save some information about what blockchain stands for in that.

We just want to know whether its possible or not. If yes, how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain-specification is just a list of storage key / value pairs.

So you can select a random key, and set some text as the value of that storage, and then insert that in your genesis block.

From there, this text will live in your blockchain storage forever.

Using a text to hex tool:

```
// Key
":my_statement:" = 0x3a6d795f73746174656d656e743a
// Value
"This is the text I want to store." = 0x5468697320697320746865207465787420492077616e7420746f2073746f72652e
```

Then you update your chain specification:

```json
"genesis": {
    "raw": {
      "top": {
        "0x3a6d795f73746174656d656e743a": "0x5468697320697320746865207465787420492077616e7420746f2073746f72652e",
...
```

Comment: This method inserts the text in the the genesis storage, not the genesis Block. While this may be useful for many cases, it is not the same as eg "Chancellor on Brink of Second Bailout For Banks" which I believe is what the question is asking for.